# convert sequences in input data set for LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am completely new to python and LSTM. I have a data set looks like this ( more than 600 labels):

Label,sequence

1,18 2 32 38 20 3314 3315 3316 3317 3318 3319

1,536 794 795 960 25 335 336 26 27

1,296 23 24 25 28 28 336 26 27

1,112 30 28 336 26 27

2,296 23 24 1955 1955 348 27 437

2,112 31 426 3724 3714 3715 3715 529 390 391 390 531

3,1300

3,1300 1320 1321 1322 1322

3,1303 1304 1305 1306 1307 1309 1357 1333

3,1323 1324 1325 1326 1327 1328

3,1300 1320

....

So as I searched input data form LSTM in Keras must be in 3D shape. I do not know how I can convert these data to suitable format. I found these code but not sure how I can use it:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, 16))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, batch=16)
```

Please advise me how I can reshape my data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have varying length sequences for each label, the first step would be to [pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences) to have all sequences padded up to some max length. You will obtain something like `(samples, max_seq_length, 1)`. Now you can pass into `LSTM(..., input_shape=(max_seq_length, 1))`. To let the LSTM skip timesteps you have use a [Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) layer *before* the LSTM. So padding sequences will reshape your data, masking will skips the padded data and LSTM will process the sequence now.

Comment: Thank you it was really a big help.
So I have implemented a code which gives me Train_set and Test_set as 2D arrays (e.g. (2000,500) and (857,500) respectively) and train_labels and test_labels 1D arrays (2000) and (875). I have 2 questions:
1) How I can reshape these array to appropriate format for LSTM?
2) I found Masking like: model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features))) , what could be timesteps and features in my case? I found this one too: mx = ma.masked_values (x, -9999.) but not sure which one is better for my data set?